# Torbutton can't connect to Vidalia in Firefox 12 in Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, firefox, tor

I may be missing something obvious, but really can't figure it out.

I've installed the latest Vidalia from torproject.org, and installed the Torbutton addon for Firefox with it in my system running Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Vidalia starts successfully and indicates I am connected to the Tor network. However, after I click the Torbutton in Firefox to activate it, and try to browse to websites, I get errors saying Firefox can't connect to the proxy server.

How do I troubleshoot this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the proxy settings in the torbutton preferences and make sure, there are no inadequate manual settings. Automatic settings should work fine, if you have no special setup.

If this does not help, check (eg. via netstat) that Tor is listening on the loopback interface on the expected port (9050 by default) and that there is no personal firewall blocking connections to this port. You might want to check this by connecting to this port with telnet.

Also check that Polipo is running and listening on the expected port (8118 by default) if you want to use it. As above, check that you are able to connect to this port.

Note, that Firefox (or Torbutton) does not connect to Vidalia even in working setups. Vidalia is only a frontend to control Tor. You want Firefox to connect to Tor (either directly or through Polipo).